# Maximum value of $8v_1 - 6v_2 - v_1^2 - v_2^2$ subject to $v_1^2+v_2^2\leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, qcqp

> Given that $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
>   $$g(v_1,v_2) = 8v_1 - 6v_2 - v_1^2 - v_2^2$$
>   find the maximum value of $g$ subject to the constraint $v_1^2+v_2^2\leq 1.$

My attempt:

Note that 
$$g(v_1,v_2) = 8v_1 - 6v_2 - v_1^2 - v_2^2 = -(v_1-4)^2 - (v_2+3)^2 + 25.$$
So $g$ is a decreasing function.

So, the maximum value of $g$ lies on the circumference of $v_1^2+v_2^2 = 1.$
It suffices to find the intersection between $(0,0)$ and $(4,-3)$ as $(4,-3)$ is the peak point of $g.$

The intersection point lies on both $v_1^2+v_2^2 = 1$ and $v_2 = -\frac{3}{4}v_1.$
Solving the simultaneous equation gives that 
$$v_1 = \frac{4}{5}, \quad v_2 = -\frac{3}{5}.$$
So, maximum value of $g$ is 
$$g\left(\frac{4}{5}, -\frac{3}{5}\right) = 9.$$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: If you have an argument that allows you to replace the inequality constraint with an equality constraint, then you can use polar coordinates to transform the problem into  an unconstrained one that can be solved using simple trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is correct but it is not clear what you mean by $g$ is a decreasing function and "find the intersection between $(0,0)$ etc."

So, here is another way using Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$8v_1 - 6v_2 \leq \sqrt{8^2+6^2}\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2} = 10 \sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}$$

$$g(v_1,v_2)\leq 10\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}- (v_1^2 + v_2^2)=t(10-t) \mbox{ with } t = \sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}$$

$t(10-t)$ is strictly increasing for $0\leq t \leq 5 \Rightarrow$ maximum of $g$ is reached for $t=\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2} =1$: $1(10-1)=\boxed{9}$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is very nice indeed. All that is needed is to explain the part about 'decreasing function' more clearly. E.g.

So we must minimise the distance between $(4,-3)$ and $(v_1,v_2)$ whilst keeping  $(v_1,v_2)$ in the unit disc.

Then you can continue with "The required point lies on both ...".

Answer (score 1):

You arrived at the right result. It would have been more intuitive if you had observed that

$$g(v_1,v_2) = -(v_1-4)^2-(v_2+3)^2+25=-d^2+25$$

where

$$d=\sqrt{(v_1-4)^2+(v_2+3)^2 }$$
 is the distance between the points $(v_1,v_2)$ and $(4,-3)$. To maximum $g(v_1,v_2)$ it to minimize $d$, which is to identify the closest point within the circle to the point $(4,-3)$. Geometrically, the closest point is the intersection between the circle  $v_1^2 + v_2^2 = 1$ and the center line $v_2=-\frac34v_1$.